# Extracting part of a specific column in text file

Tags: text-processing

```
ffmj0010.09o:FFMJ                                                  MARKER NAME
ffmj0020.09o:BRMU                                                  MARKER NAME
```

In this text file (2 lines and no space between the lines) I need to extract 4 characters after ":" ("FFMJ", "BRMU") and save them in another text file. Which command do I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*:\(.\{4\}\).*/\1/' in > out
```

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: stops the command / starts the pattern
- `.*:`: matches any number of any character until the last `:` character and a `:` character
- `\(.\{4\}\)`: matches and groups 4 occurences of any character
- `.*`: matches any number of any character
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `\1`: backreference replaced with the first captured group
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the pattern flags

Sample output on the example file:

```
% cat in
ffmj0010.09o:FFMJ MARKER NAME
ffmj0020.09o:BRMU MARKER NAME
% sed 's/.*:\(.\{4\}\).*/\1/' in > out
% cat out
FFMJ
BRMU
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that you want exactly 4 characters before end of the line, you can do:

```
grep -Eo '.{4}$' file.txt >out.txt
```

Otherwise you can go for `grep` with PCRE to get all characters after `:` till the end of the line:

```
grep -Po '.*:\K[^:]+$' file.txt >out.txt
```

You can also use `bash` parameter expansion:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "${line##*:}"; done <file.txt >out.txt
```

**EDIT:**

As @kos pointed out I might have misunderstood the question, if you want exactly 4 characters after `:` you can do:

```
grep -Po '.*:\K.{4}' file.txt >out.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` and multiple delimiters

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{print $2}' in > out
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat in
ffmj0010.09o:FFMJ                                                  MARKER NAME
ffmj0020.09o:BRMU                                                  MARKER NAME

$ awk -F'[: ]' '{print $2}' in 
FFMJ
BRMU
```

Comment: A much better awk answer than mine, forgot about multiple delimiters!

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
cat oldFile | grep -o ":[A-Z]*" | grep -o "[A-Z]*" > newFile
```

```bsh
cat oldFile |                                         # Read the file
               grep 
                    -o                                # Only give the greped data
                       ":[A-Z]*"                      # Find a : followed by 4
                                                      #  4 capital letters
                                 | grep -o "[A-Z]*"   # Remove the : from that
```

Then the `> newFile` outputs to a file.

On the example:

```
ffmj0010.09o:FFMJ MARKER NAME
ffmj0020.09o:BRMU MARKER NAME
```

goes to

```
FFMJ
BRMU
```

Comment: `grep -o ":[A-Z]*" oldFile | grep -o "[A-Z]*" > newFile`

Comment: You could simplify this to a single command by adding the `-P` option and using a positive look-behind: `grep -Po "(?<=:)[A-Z]*" oldFile > newFile`

Comment: @kos I don't understand how that works so I'll leave it at that. This is the method I go for to remove unwanted strings (or get wanted ones) but that is a useful trick.

Comment: @A.B. yeah, personal preference of mine is cat.

Comment: Basically It just means "if what preceeds what is following me (me=`(?<=:)`) is a `:` character, then *don't discard this as a non-match*, but don't match me". Also in this case just `grep -Po ":\K[A-Z]*" oldFile > newFile` (`\K`=clear what is matched until now) would do. It would save you one command :D